# Design a Floating Action button with More menu [Xamarin.Forms (Portable)]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, floating-action-button

Is it possible to develop the Floating Action Button with more menu as per the attached screenshot? I can use the Floating Action Button but I want to add more menus in Floating Action Button.

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese gothrough this github link...

[ActionButton.cs](https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl.Controls/blob/master/NControl.Controls/ActionButton.cs)

Hope this meets your idea...